# Hyperref does not work in autart.cls

Tags: hyperref

I’m currently preparing a paper for submission to the journal ‘Automatica.’ I initially typeset the paper using the ‘elsarticle.cls’. However, after submission, the corresponding editor emailed me and suggested that to re-typeset the paper using ‘autart.cls.’ Here’s my problem: It seems that \hyperref is not working! For instance, when I want to cite an equation using \eqref{}, the hyperlink won’t be active (it just shows the number of the equation). This problem also persists when referring to a figure or theorem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you all. In the following, I add the packages that I'm using.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=MidnightBlue]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}

\thanks[footnoteinfo]{This paper was not presented at any IFAC meeting.}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Sec}

\begin{align} \label{Eq1}
  F = m.a\textrm{.}
\end{align}

Consider the equation \eqref{Eq1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a full Minimal Working Example recreating your problem all the way to `\end{document}`? When I write a short document with that class and those packages, it seems like `\eqref` is working perfectly well.

Comment: You are absolutely right. As you proposed, I wrote a short document, and `\eqref` worked perfectly. But when I added the `\frontmatter` environment, I encountered the same problem. As you asked, I will add a full Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 4):

The class makes a bad error: its `\frontmatter` command issues `\NoHyper` instead of enclosing the whole thing in `\begin{NoHyper}...\end{NoHyper}`, so the adjustments made by `\endNoHyper` are lost.

Since `\endNoHyper` (which is executed when `\end{NoHyper}` is processed) does

```
% hyperref.sty, line 6451:
\def\endNoHyper{%
  \global\let\hyper@link\hyper@livelink
}
```

it is clear why links no longer work.

It's not wrong to use `\NoHyper` in the code for `\frontmatter`, so long as `\endNoHyper` is used somewhere, quite likely in `\endfrontmatter`.

The simplest method to fix the issue is to add `\endNoHyper` at the end of `\endfrontmatter`.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{autart}

% fix the missing \paperheight setting
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
%%%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=MidnightBlue]{hyperref}

%%% fix the missing bit in \endfrontmatter
\edef\endfrontmatter{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\endfrontmatter}% the current code
  \noexpand\endNoHyper % add \endNoHyper at the end to match \NoHyper
}
%%%

\bibliographystyle{agsm}

%\setlength{\parindent}{12pt} % you shouldn't change the class default

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Test\thanksref{footnoteinfo}}

\thanks[footnoteinfo]{This paper was not presented at any IFAC meeting.}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Sec}

\begin{align} \label{Eq1}
  F = m.a\textrm{.}
\end{align}

Consider the equation \eqref{Eq1}.

\end{document}
```

I also added the setting to `\paperheight` that's needed by `hyperref`.

[image]

Comment: It worked! I can't thank you enough.